# How do I show all folders and files in drives C, D, or E in Delphi by using ListView-like control/component?

Tags: delphi, controls

How can I implement the idea in the pictures in a Delphi project? So that there is a `TComboBox` to display drives C, D and E with icons, and when choosing a path, all folders and files with icons appear at the bottom. I think it is `TListview`, so that when I click on a path, its files appear, and when I click on any file, any of its content appear, whether other files or images.

[image: selecting drive from ComboBox]

[image: selecting path in list of folders]

Comment: I'm not really sure if it is listview or memo or item else, so Do you know the name of that item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [legacy controls from 16 bit Windows 3.1](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Win_3.1_Controls) - you can find the controls in the tab "*Win 3.1*". They are:

- `TDriveComboBox`,
- `TDirectoryListBox` and
- `TFileListBox`

...all sitting in the `Vcl.FileCtrl.pas` unit.

[image: Windows 3.1 legacy controls]

In the properties you have to link each control to the other, so they automatically work together. Here's an example DFM as text, also with a `TFilterComboBox`:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  object dcbDrive: TDriveComboBox
    DirList = dlbFolder
  end
  object dlbFolder: TDirectoryListBox
    FileList = flbFile
  end
  object flbFile: TFileListBox
  end
  object fcbFilter: TFilterComboBox
    FileList = flbFile
  end
end
```

Comment: Wooow,Thank you very much man, I did not know these items, really thank you pro, thank you again for your time and effort, I really appreciate it < =) >